# UIBezierPath partially stroke

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath, cgcontext

I have this code to draw a rectangle which is rounded rect only on one side.

[image: this one]

```
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    let lineWidth = CGFloat(4)


    let pathRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: pathRect.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: lineWidth, left: lineWidth, bottom: lineWidth, right: 0)), byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 7, height: 7))

    context.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    path.fill()

    context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
}
```

I want to stroke it with red color on all but the right edge (no stroke on the right edge). How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll have to create your own path.

A couple of observations:

- Don’t use the `rect` parameter. The `rect` is what is being asked to being drawn at this point in time, which may not be the entire view. Use `bounds` when figuring out what the overall path should be.
- I might inset the path so that the stroke stays within the bounds of the view.
- You can make this `@IBDesignable` if you want to also be able to see it rendered in IB.
- You don’t really need `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. The `UIKit` methods `fill()`, `stroke()`, `setFill()`, and `setStroke()` methods automatically use the current context.

Thus:

```
@IBDesignable
class OpenRightView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 4      { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var radius: CGFloat = 7         { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .red { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let pathRect = bounds.inset(by: .init(top: lineWidth / 2, left: lineWidth / 2, bottom: lineWidth / 2, right: 0))

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.maxX, y: pathRect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX + radius, y: pathRect.minY))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.minY + radius), controlPoint: pathRect.origin)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.maxY - radius))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX + radius, y: pathRect.maxY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.maxX, y: pathRect.maxY))

        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()

        strokeColor.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

---

Theoretically, it might be more efficient to use `CAShapeLayer` and let Apple take care of the `draw(_:)` for us. E.g., they may have optimized the rendering to handle partial view updates, etc.

That might look like the following:

```
@IBDesignable
class OpenRightView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 4      { didSet { updatePath() } }
    @IBInspectable var radius: CGFloat = 7         { didSet { updatePath() } }
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .black { didSet { shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .red { didSet { shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor } }

    lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
}

private extension OpenRightView {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let pathRect = bounds.inset(by: .init(top: lineWidth / 2, left: lineWidth / 2, bottom: lineWidth / 2, right: 0))

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.maxX, y: pathRect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX + radius, y: pathRect.minY))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.minY + radius), controlPoint: pathRect.origin)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.maxY - radius))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX + radius, y: pathRect.maxY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: pathRect.maxX, y: pathRect.maxY))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    }
}
```